# Neo4j/Cypher - Returning a nested JSON object with linked nodes

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I have parent comments and child comments. I want to be able to group together my child comments as one object that is part of my Parent object. Here is my Neo4j code:

```
MATCH (c:Comment)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(cc:Comment)
WHERE c.GUID=$GUID
RETURN collect({comment: c, subcomment: cc})
```

And here is the JSON output that I receive:

```
[
    {
        "parentComment": {
            "identity": {
                "low": 6418,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Action",
                "Comment"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "GUID": "77750e90-77cf-4e40-9753-87ba828366a5",
                "text": "This is a comment",
                "type": "Comment",
                "timestamp": 20171220111906416
            }
        },
        "childComment": {
            "identity": {
                "low": 8404,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Comment"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "user": "James",
                "text": "Test comment",
                "timestamp": 20180314142848576
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "parentComment": {
            "identity": {
                "low": 6418,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Action",
                "Comment"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "GUID": "77750e90-77cf-4e40-9753-87ba828366a5",
                "text": "This is a comment",
                "type": "Comment",
                "timestamp": 20171220111906416
            }
        },
        "childComment": {
            "identity": {
                "low": 8659,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Comment"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "user": "James S",
                "text": "TEST",
                "timestamp": "today"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see it is printing the parent comment twice with a different child each time. What do I need to include in my Cypher query to group the child nodes together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return a map projection, this way:

```
MATCH (c:Comment)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(cc:Comment)
WHERE c.GUID=$GUID
RETURN {comment : c, subcomments: collect(cc)}
```

Comment: Hey Bruno, thanks for answering - this gives me a Syntax Error however ('collect is not defined')

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake - it does work! I had copied it across wrongly. I'll accept your answer is as correct when the system allows me to,  thank you!